# Receiver class does not define or inherit an implementation of the interface java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, interface, comparable

I have been stumped on this issue for quite a while. Could not find anything wrong with my code online, everything regarding structure seems correct. Spits out error message:  "Receiver class ComparableTriangle does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract int compareTo(java.lang.Object)' of interface java.lang.Comparable." (Line 118)

The compareTo method works correctly, just the Collections.sort does not work.

Any idea?

`

```
import java.lang.Math.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;  

 class GeometricObject {
    
}

class Triangle extends GeometricObject {
    ... triangle parameters
}

class ComparableTriangle extends Triangle implements Comparable<Triangle>,Cloneable {
  /** Construct a ComparableTriangle with specified properties */
  public ComparableTriangle(double side1, double side2, double side3) {
    super(side1, side2, side3);
  }
  // Compares the object (t) to the parameter being input (t2)
  @Override public int compareTo(ComparableTriangle param) {
    if (this.getArea() > param.getArea()) { // this > t1
      System.out.println("Triangle 1 is bigger.");
      return 1;
    }
    else if (this.getArea() < param.getArea()) {
      System.out.println("Triangle 2 is bigger.");
      return -1;
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Both triangles are equal.");
      return 0;
    }
  }
  // Clones the object input. Throws exception if not supported.
  protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    {  
        System.out.println(this.getArea());
        System.out.println(this.getPerimeter());
        return super.clone();
    }
  }
}





public class TriangleClass7A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {  
          ... variables
          ArrayList<ComparableTriangle> tri = new ArrayList<ComparableTriangle>();
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          while (true) {
            ... variable input by user
            }
            ComparableTriangle t = new ComparableTriangle(side1,side2,side3);
            tri.add(t);
          }
          System.out.println("Done.");
          Collections.sort(tri);
        }
    }


}
```

`

I have tried many small changes, but the structure seems to match every other implementation I have found online, but doesn't work in my code. Using Visual Studio Code if that at all matters.

Edit 1:
I tried changing the class to "class ComparableTriangle extends Triangle implements Comparable,Cloneable", but exact same error. No change at all.
Clarification: The error spit out by Collections.sort is a runtime error, not compiler error. If I only create one triangle object, the program works just fine.

Comment: ComparableTriangle is comparable to a Triangle, but not to itself, which is a ComparableTriangle

Comment: Your class implements `Comparable<Triangle>`, for that reason method signature of `compareTo(ComparableTriangle param)` doesn't match. Hence, it's not a valid method overriding, and that's what compiler is telling you.

Comment: I would not expect this code to compile, but the short answer is: if your type implements `Comparable<Something>`, then it needs to implement the method `compareTo(Something param)` exactly.  It cannot implement `compareTo(SomethingElse param)`.  Your code violates that.

Comment: @LouisWasserman It's a runtime error when it reaches Collections.sort(tri). I'll try that, but I had to change it to ComparableTriangle previously for an issue.

Comment: In that case, you will need to change it to `Comparable<ComparableTriangle>` as well.  You should also tell us about any warnings in the compilation of your code.

Comment: (OP) Exact same error when I changed the class implement to "class ComparableTriangle extends Triangle implements Comparable<ComparableTriangle>,Cloneable"

Comment: *changing the class to "class ComparableTriangle extends Triangle implements Comparable,Cloneable"* - `implements Comparable,Cloneable`, you mean you've implemented `Comparable` of row type (with no generic parameter), or `Comparable<ComparableTriangle>` ? Also, did you **recompile** the code?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I have tried both. Same error. No matter what I try, the compareTo method is simply not picked up by the system.
Also, yes I recompile.